# VBA - Arrayformula to a range stored as array variable

Tags: worksheet-function

I need to apply a formula array to dynamic ranges in my spreadsheets, which for a fixed size range works fine using for example:

```
Selection.Offset(2, 0).FormulaArray = "=(SUM((Exx:Eyy-Fxx:Fyy)^2)/X)^.5"
```

But the ranges don't have a fixed size and position in all my spreadsheets, so I select them initially and then I store them as arrays of dimension 1 and then redim to length N.

These arrays will be named, for example, A for the range Exx:Eyy and B for the range Fxx:Fyy, so then, when I want to apply the same aforementioned array formula, I get the error `Compile Error: type mismatch when using the array variables instead of the explicit ranges` with:

```
Selection.Offset(2, 0).FormulaArray = "=(SUM((" & A & "-" & B & ")^2)/X)^.5"
```

And if I don't use the quotes and ampersand, of course, I got the error `name`.

I also tried to use the `evaluate` property on the right hand side of the equality and it works without errors, but in this way I don't get the same value as using formula array :/

Can anyone give me a hand please?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question what is the data type of your arrays string / range?
It seems that excel

- either don't know which sheet do you mean (if your reference is stored as a string, than add sheet to the address too (e.g. sheet1!a1:b1))
- either excel misinterpret your data (if your reference is stored in range try to use A.address instead of just A)